# Update state of a component in another file

Tags: flutter, dart

In my settings screen, users can view their information and they are allowed to edit their username. the page is structured of three components that are programmed in separate files, the settings screen looks like this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ap = Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context, listen: false);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.settingsTitle),
        centerTitle: true,
        leading: GestureDetector(
          child: Icon(
            Icons.arrow_back_ios,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          ProfilePicture(),
          SizedBox(
            height: 13,
          ),
          UserInfo(),
          SizedBox(
            height: 40,
          ),
          UserSettings(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

users can update their username from the `UserSettings()` component and here is the function of updating username:

```
changeUserName() async {
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Center(
                child:
                    Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.changeNameDialogTitle)),
            content: Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: userNameController,
                    validator: ((value) {
                      if (value!.isEmpty) {
                        return AppLocalizations.of(context)!
                            .changeNameDialogValidation;
                      }
                    }),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText:
                            AppLocalizations.of(context)!.chanheNameDialogHint,
                        suffixIcon: Icon(
                          Icons.account_circle,
                          color: Colors.purple,
                        )),
                  ),
                  TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                          var collection =
                              FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users');
                          collection
                              .doc(user!.uid)
                              .update({"name": userNameController.text});
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                          Fluttertoast.showToast(
                              msg: AppLocalizations.of(context)!
                                  .changeNameSuccessfully);
                        }
                      },
                      child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.changeName))
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        });
  }
```

now whenever user is updating the username from `UserSettings()` file the name should be updated directly in the `UserInfo()` file but the problem is its not taking the effect live i should refresh the page in order to see the changes, here is the `UserInfo()` component:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text(
          "${loggedInUser.name}",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 5,
        ),
        Text("${loggedInUser.email}",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400)),
        SizedBox(
          height: 30,
        ),
        IntrinsicHeight(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              userStats(context, loggedInUser.challenges,
                  AppLocalizations.of(context)!.challenge),
              verticalLine(),
              userStats(context, loggedInUser.winnings,
                  AppLocalizations.of(context)!.wins),
              verticalLine(),
              userStats(context, loggedInUser.events,
                  AppLocalizations.of(context)!.events)
            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```

so to summarize am trying to update state of a component live from another component that exists in another file, I appreciate any help.

Comment: you need to use a state management package like provider, block, getx, riverpod, etc to achieve this, but for what I can see on your code you are saving the new name directly on firebase (?) so you should read it from firebase using a StreamBuilder to get live changes, but I wont say this is the most cost effective way to do this

Comment: @CarlosSandoval Thanks for comment, am trying to study the callbacks now but am still not sure how to do a callback function